# Can I debug by CSS code in easy way for beginner?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS coding and wants to know where I can debug by CSS code in easy way ?

Comment: What do you mean an easy way? If you don't know how a css property works, you can't troubleshoot is, so if something looks wrong you can't exactly figure out what's wrong if you dont know the property that might be causing it in the first place

Comment: Like structure query language like cobol I know we are having debugger so came to know what is the value it is taking flow of the coding ...etc

Comment: There's no "flow" to css, there's not any execution, it's just your browser applying properties, every browser has devtools that will show you which rules take precedence, which rules are overwritten etc, but there's not anything similar to a "debugger" for css because css isn't a language that actually executes anything

Answer (score 0):

You can run your CSS code through a validator like https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ or you can use the browser dev tools by right clicking the page and selecting inspect. This would allow you to hover and click on each element to see the attached styles. I haven't used validators since school, but I spend all day in the dev tools panel.

Comment: Hi thanks, it will validate the code, but I want to debug it. Pl comment